# Program waits for API call to finish

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, autodesk-inventor

So I am working on a project where I call the export window in Inventor via the Inventor API like so :

```
Dim Commander As CommandManager
Commander = ThisApplication.CommandManager
Dim Controller As ControlDefinition
Controller = Commander.ControlDefinitions.Item("AppFileExportCADFormatCmd")
Call Controller.Execute()
```

This code works just fine for opening the "Save As" window in Inventor but my VB program will hang on the line

```
Call Controller.Execute()
```

Until I close the "Save As" window.

My aim is to open up the window and then automatically press the Save button, but the only thing stopping me is the "freeze" at the Call line.

Comment: Have you tried doing this on another thread or even using a task?

Comment: Not familiar with Inventor but a Save As dialog is usually a modal dialog.

Comment: @Mary correct, but user could have something already going on in the background and calling this would be a blocking call... It would be best if user would update the post to get a better view of what they are doing.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I am not really familiar with threads and tasks but I will try to look into.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ So I got it working. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @FloydHD Awesome, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I used two Threads (I updated the post).

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working with defining two new Threads with the Address of my two Subs which I want to run simultaneously. And then started both Threads.

This is the Code :

```
Dim CADFastExportThread As New Thread(AddressOf CADFastExport)
Dim CADFastSaveThread As New Thread(AddressOf CADFastSave)
CADFastExportThread.Start()
CADFastSaveThread.Start()
```